# ServletException - property not found? What's wrong here?

Tags: java, jsf

I'm just setting up a simple testclass. Code completions works in eclipse, but I cannot launch the page:

backing bean:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class TestBean {

    public String getString() {
        return "click me";
    }
}
```

jsf:

```
<h:commandButton value="#{testBean.getString()}" />
```

also tried testBean.string and testBean.getString.

exception:

```
    javax.servlet.ServletException: input.xhtml @41,52 value="#{testBean.getString()}":
The class 'TestBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy' does not have the property 'getString'.
```

What is wrong here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSF you don't use parentheses or the "get" part of the name.

Use this instead.

```
<h:commandButton value="#{testBean.string}" />
```

Comment: This is really strange. If I name the method getMyString(), then I have to use testBean.getMyString().

Comment: JSF has a duality of thinking on this matter.
Properties are accessed by property name, not by accessor method name.
Listeners, like actionListener, are specified by method name.

Comment: This is not specific to JSF. This is specific to EL (and Javabeans) spec.